# Debugging issue in VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Okay , weird things are happening to me again. This morning when i started my ASP.NET application, worked on it a bit and now when i try to publish it. I'm getting served with an error where i can't seem to find any documentation on

```
Error   1   Unable to apply a change while debugging. Source file '\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs' was reloaded. You must restart the debugging session.
```

Anyone knows what to do with this ?

Comment: Were you debugging while trying to publish?

Comment: Have you tried to stop your VS debugging and then publish your project?

Comment: No to the first and yes to the second comment

Comment: It wasn't a first and second question ;). Try to stop debugging and to publish afterwards.

Comment: I just ran into this same problem (read more carefully, Sascha :). Debugger was off, and I halted my web application server. Solution for me was to restart VS.

Comment: Restarting was also the fix for me. Some info to help determine the cause: solution containing an MVC 3 project, using the Development Server, connected to TFS 2010.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all addons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try closing the ASP.NET Development Server. It will be in the system tray (next to time), just double click it and click "Close" then just run again.

Or you can open Task Manager and end the process of Image Name: WebDev.Webserver...

Answer (score 11):

1. Confirm that neither this instance of visual studio nor another is debugging the binaries in question.
2. **Restart Visual Studio. This will usually fix the problem.**
3. If that still doesn't work, try disabling all addons and restarting visual studio one more time.
4. Finally, as a last resort, reinstalling visual studio has a way of fixing seemingly unfixable problems.