# Unable to apply a change while debugging

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I'm getting a strange error when attempting to debug a console app that's referencing a workflow service.

'Unable to apply a change while debugging. Source file '...\myService\obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_...cs' was reloaded. You must restart the debugging session.'

I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary and this comes up as soon as I start debugging. There is a similar question here [Debugging issue in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391314/debugging-issue-in-vs2010) but the only answers suggest restarting visual studio/development server which hasn't helped me. Does anyone have a better explanation and or possible fix for this? I've tried restarting everything and looking into the temporary file referenced in the error message with no luck.

Answer (score 10):

I got this issue in VS 2012, and I wasn't even debugging - I was trying to deploy. Restarting both VS and my IIS instance did the trick.